# Error:"No such column 'Product__r' on sobject of type SBQQ__QuoteLine__c" when marking primary quote

Tags: quote, cpq, steelbrick

We're configuring our instance of Salesforce CPQ (Steelbrick) and running into an error where when any user marks a quote primary on the detail page an error appears at the top where the "Recalculating" text usually shows.

The error states "No such column 'Product__r' on sobject of type SBQQ__QuoteLine__c"

Looking into it most all forum posts say the same, that it's either a product or price rule, but we have none, not even any inactive, that reference just "Product__r". We do have one that references "SBQQ__Product__r.Name" but even deactivating that price rule doesn't change the error.

[image: ErrorMessage]

Comment: Can you check the if field API is `Product__c`

Comment: there is no field called product__r on quoteline. it's SBQQ__Product__c

Comment: @nightcrawler exactly, which is why I'm using SBQQ__Product__r.Name in the price rule.

Comment: do you have any trigger on quote, quoteline, opportunity or opportunityitem?

Comment: @nightcrawler other than the ones that come by default with the managed package, we only have one, and that one doesn't touch quotes at all. In fact it's to convert Opportunity Line Items when the quote is in the Closed Won stage.